# Android InApp Managed billing with RESTORE_TRANSACTION

Tags: android, in-app-billing

how to use RESTORE_TRANSACTION  in android in-App implementation for one time payment if application is uninstall and reinstall again InApp product access free

Comment: Google already provide Restore transaction for in app purchase you just need to use resotre methhod because google maintain the purchase history

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Dungeons sample](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_integrate.html#billing-download). Basically, you set SharedPreference flag, and if it is not there, you assume the app is installed for the first time, and send a restore transactions request and set the flag. If the flag is there, you skip the restore part, and just start the app.

Comment: i this i help full for update means user just install new version but not for re installation scenario if any code available then please tell me

Comment: If the user reinstalled, the preferences will be empty, so the flag won't be set. Preferences are retained when upgrading, so the flag will be set. The Dungeons sample has exactly this code, check it out (link in the answer above).